# Boost C++ date_time microsec_clock and second_clock

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, utc, clock

I discovered a strange result in Boost C++ date time library. There is inconsistency between `microsec_clock` and `second_clock`, and I don't understand why is that. I am using Windows XP 32-bits

My snip of code:

```
using namespace boost::posix_time;
...
ptime now = second_clock::universal_time();
std::cout << "Current Time is: "<< to_iso_extended_string(now)<< std::endl;
ptime now_2 = microsec_clock::universal_time();
std::cout << "Current Time is: "<< to_iso_extended_string(now_2)<< std::endl;
...
```

The print-out I expected are current time without miliseconds and with milliseonds. However, what I have in my pc is:

```
2009-10-14T16:07:38  
1970-06-24T20:36:09.375890
```

I don't understand why there is a weired date (year 1970???) in my `microsec_clock` time. Related documentation for Boost: [link to boost date time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.ptime_class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what could be wrong for you; the exact same code works for me.

```
$ cat > test.cc
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
using namespace boost::posix_time;
int main() {
    ptime now = second_clock::universal_time();
    std::cout << "Current Time is: "<< to_iso_extended_string(now)<< std::endl;
    ptime now_2 = microsec_clock::universal_time();
    std::cout << "Current Time is: "<< to_iso_extended_string(now_2)<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
^D
$ c++ -lboost_date_time test.cc
$ ./a.out
Current Time is: 2009-10-14T16:26:55
Current Time is: 2009-10-14T16:26:55.586295
```

Implementation-wise, `second_clock` uses [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) and `microsec_clock` uses [`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) or [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397.aspx) underneath, depending on the platform.  Something appears wrong with your platform -- what is your OS and version?

---

What is your Boost version?  If it is 1.38 or lower, upgrade to 1.39 or apply the fix to [#2809](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2809) manually.

```
--- boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp  (revision 53621)
+++ boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp  (revision 53622)
@@ -96,9 +96,7 @@
     {
         /* shift is difference between 1970-Jan-01 & 1601-Jan-01
         * in 100-nanosecond intervals */
-        const uint64_t c1 = 27111902UL;
-        const uint64_t c2 = 3577643008UL; // issues warning without 'UL'
-        const uint64_t shift = (c1 << 32) + c2;
+        const uint64_t shift = 116444736000000000ULL; // (27111902 << 32) + 3577643008

         union {
             FileTimeT as_file_time;
```

Windows FileTime has a different offset from UNIX time, and the code that was in Boost before would not generate the correct offset difference in certain optimizing compilers.

Comment: I am using Win32 system, Windows XP SP2 32 bits to be exact.

Comment: I am using 1.39 already with Eclipse 3.4.1 and MingW 3.4. Also, I am having the warning: Description Resource Path Location Type
C:/boost/boost_1_39/boost/date_time/filetime_functions.hpp left shift count >= width of type CommercialDetection line 101 C/C++ Problem as well

Comment: Hmm, I thought this fix was in 1.39 but I can double-check.

Answer (score 1):

The 1970 date most likely comes from the way [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is represented, as seconds from January 1 1970.  I would guess that maybe it is somehow getting the system uptime in milliseconds and interpreting it as seconds since 1/1/1970.  An uptime of a little over 4 hours would come up with this date.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `second_clock`, the `microsec_clock::universal_time` documentation mentions: *Returns the UTC time based on **computer settings**.*
You should check your hardware clock settings (or where-ever microsec gets its values from).

*edit:*

If its not related to your computers settings it would have to be an misbehaviour in boost, which i highly doubt.

Comment: Very good point, and I also found this: 
Get the UTC time using a sub second resolution clock. On Unix systems this is implemented using GetTimeOfDay. On most Win32 platforms it is implemented using ftime. Win32 systems often do not achieve microsecond resolution via this API. If higher resolution is critical to your application test your platform to see the achieved resolution.

===>
I am using Win32 system, so maybe there is no such resolution at all in my pc. That might be the reason. However, the print-out did give me a date, then where do those numbers come from?...

Comment: Implementation-wise it generates a time_type from the current date and ftime() in create_time() if i see that right.

Comment: And if ftime() doesn't support sub second resolution i'd expect to lose the high resolution and a fallback to the next-best resolution.

Comment: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/2809 Misbehavior in Boost may be more likely than you think.

Comment: Ok, but in general less likely then user mistakes or invalid settings. This seems to be limited to MingW - for me it works fine on WinXP/VC8/boost 1.38.